# VBA changes from a cell

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, export

To explain my title, basically i have a macro code which ill display in sec that is requesting number of days that need it to be exported from our shared mailbox. Now on a daily basis I have to change the number of days we need to export and is getting really frustrating. The following line is in question:

```
If VBA.DateValue(VBA.Now) - VBA.DateValue(vItem.ReceivedTime) <= 10 Then
```

That number 10 needs to change on a daily basis so i tried with active cell but no success as i get a runtime error 438.

So my question is: Is there a way that in a separated spreadsheet to input the number of days i need to export and that line in question can take the information from there and carry on with the code ?

Please see full code below.

```
    Sub Accomplished()
   Application.Run "Module5.OptimizeCode_Begin"
    Dim Folder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim sFolders As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim iRow As Integer, oRow As Integer
    Dim MailBoxName As String, Pst_Folder_Name  As String
    Dim vItems As Outlook.Items
    Dim vItem As Object

     'Mailbox or PST Main Folder Name (As how it is displayed in your Outlook Session)
    MailBoxName = "Castle Donington Time and Attendance"

     'Mailbox Folder or PST Folder Name (As how it is displayed in your Outlook Session)
    Pst_Folder_Name = "Accomplished" 'Sample "Inbox" or "Sent Items"

     'To directly a Folder at a high level
     'Set Folder = Outlook.Session.Folders(MailBoxName).Folders(Pst_Folder_Name)

     'To access a main folder or a subfolder (level-1)

    For Each Folder In Outlook.Session.Folders(MailBoxName).Folders
        If VBA.UCase(Folder.Name) = VBA.UCase(Pst_Folder_Name) Then GoTo Label_Folder_Found
        For Each sFolders In Folder.Folders
            If VBA.UCase(sFolders.Name) = VBA.UCase(Pst_Folder_Name) Then
                Set Folder = sFolders
                GoTo Label_Folder_Found
            End If
        Next sFolders
    Next Folder


Label_Folder_Found:
    If Folder.Name = "" Then
        MsgBox "Invalid Data in Input"
GoTo End_Lbl1:
    End If


     'Read Through each Mail and export the details to Excel for Email Archival
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Activate

    Folder.Items.sort "Received"

     'Insert Column Headers
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(1, 1) = "Sender"
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(1, 2) = "Subject"
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(1, 3) = "Date"
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(1, 4) = "Sent"
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(1, 5) = "EmailID"
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(1, 6) = "Categories"
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(1, 7) = "Parent"
     'ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 6) = "Body"

     'Export eMail Data from PST Folder
    oRow = 1
    Set vItems = Folder.Items
    For iRow = 1 To vItems.Count
        Set vItem = vItems.Item(iRow)
        If vItem.Class = 43 Then
         'If condition to import mails received in last 60 days
         'To import all emails, comment or remove this IF condition
        If VBA.DateValue(VBA.Now) - VBA.DateValue(vItem.ReceivedTime) <= 10 Then
            oRow = oRow + 1
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(oRow, 1).Select
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(oRow, 1) = Folder.Items.Item(iRow).SenderName
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(oRow, 2) = Folder.Items.Item(iRow).Subject
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(oRow, 3) = Folder.Items.Item(iRow).ReceivedTime
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(oRow, 4) = Folder.Items.Item(iRow).SentOn
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(oRow, 5) = Folder.Items.Item(iRow).ConversationID
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(oRow, 6) = Folder.Items.Item(iRow).Categories
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(oRow, 7) = Folder.Items.Item(iRow).Parent
            'ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Cells(oRow, 8) = Folder.Items.Item(iRow).Sent
            'ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(oRow, 6) = Folder.Items.Item(iRow).Body
             End If
        End If
    Next iRow
    MsgBox "Extration Complete ^.^"
    Set Folder = Nothing
    Set sFolders = Nothing

    ' sheet3_copypaste Macro

    Sheets("Sheet3").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-33
    Range("A2:H3001").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Full List").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

    'Format
    Sheets("Full List").Select
    Columns("D:E").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy h:mm"
    Range("D1").Select

    ' sort Macro
    Range("D6").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Full List").sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Full List").sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("D6"), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Full List").sort
        .SetRange Range("A5:I4976")
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    Range("D1").Select
End_Lbl1:
Application.Run "Module5.OptimizeCode_End"
End Sub
```

Thank you for taking interest. 
Any questions i'm happy to answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for consistency sake with excel and macros a **workbook** is a full xlsm file that contains a collection of **worksheets** (individual tabs that you put data on).  By a seperated spreadsheet I'm assuming a different workbook.

[Here](http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=454) is some useful code for getting data from a spreadsheet.

The main function GetData at the bottom, instead of storing the data in a local cell you would just put it in a variable and use that in your "<" statement.

```
Sub GetDataDemo() 

    Dim FilePath$, Row&, Column&, Address$ 

     'change constants & FilePath below to suit
     '***************************************
    Const FileName$ = "Book1.xls" 
    Const SheetName$ = "Sheet1" 
    Const NumRows& = 10 
    Const NumColumns& = 10 
    FilePath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" 
     '***************************************

    DoEvents 
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 
    If Dir(FilePath & FileName) = Empty Then 
        MsgBox "The file " & FileName & " was not found", , "File Doesn't Exist" 
        Exit Sub 
    End If 
    For Row = 1 To NumRows 
        For Column = 1 To NumColumns 
            Address = Cells(Row, Column).Address 
            Cells(Row, Column) = GetData(FilePath, FileName, SheetName, Address) 
            Columns.AutoFit 
        Next Column 
    Next Row 
    ActiveWindow.DisplayZeros = False 
End Sub 


Private Function GetData(Path, File, Sheet, Address) 
    Dim Data$ 
    Data = "'" & Path & "[" & File & "]" & Sheet & "'!" & _ 
    Range(Address).Range("A1").Address(, , xlR1C1) 
    GetData = ExecuteExcel4Macro(Data) 
End Function
```

If its from the same workbook you would just use something like

```
dim NUMDAYS as double

NUMDAYS = sheets("sheet2").range("A1").value to assign to a variable which would be used later in your macro.

If VBA.DateValue(VBA.Now) - VBA.DateValue(vItem.ReceivedTime) <= NUMDAYS Then
```

Comment: Apologies for the minor confusion it is set to the same workbook but a different sheet, also how do you think its best to distribute it as a variable.