# Populate Combobox on userform

Tags: excel, vba

I am wondering if it is possible to populate a combobox on a userform when initialized with worksheet names from a CLOSED workbook. I have researched this extensively and found one solution requiring a reference to ActiveX Data Objects 2.5 or above. But is there another, simpler way? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this post is what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36992630/vba-changes-from-a-cell/36992772#36992772 Look specifically at the function `GetData` (at the end of the code block). Is makes use of `ExecuteExcel4Macro` method.

Comment: I used that before for retrieving table headers and didn't think to use it for sheet names. That may do the trick. Thank you, @Ralph!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.

```
Dim wb as workbook
Dim ws as worksheet

set wb = application.workbooks.open(<your workbook>, true, true)
set ws = wb.worksheets(<your worksheet>)
```

After setting the ws with you worksheet you can access the data you need.

P.S. Sorry my english

Comment: The OP wants to work on a **closed** workbook. Yet, you are proposing to `.Open` the workbook. How does that answer the question?

Comment: Hi @Ralplh, I understand that, at the moment of populate the combobox the workbook will be closed, and then he need to get the data. Probably I misunderstood the question.

Comment: As far as I understood the question: the values for the combo box are in a closed Excel file. The OP wishes to populate the combo box without opening the Excel file (in Excel). But since the values (to populate the combo box) are in that Excel file he/she is looking for other means to read that Excel file (other than opening that Excel file). One way to accomplish that (reading data from an Excel file without opening it in Excel) is to use `ActiveX Data Objects 2.5 or above`. But maybe I just didn't understand the question correctly.

Comment: Ok, I understand now. Thank's @Ralph. My answer is not useful.